# Android How to Pass a JSON Object as a url parameter

Tags: java, android, json

I have a requirement where i have to pass a json object in a url as a paramter. Here is my url

```
http://test.amazonaws.com/xyx/company/12/user/1/contact/{contactActivityJSON}/key/abccedrf/contacts?op=readsave
```

Now the contactActivityJSON has the following structure

```
{
    "user": {},
    "event": {
        "id": 1,
    },
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": "-1",
            "eventId": 1,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "test",
                    "value": "CallMe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i am having problem encoding the JSON object into the URL. I am using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Writer strWriter = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(strWriter, request.getRequestBody());
String jsonString = strWriter.toString();
String sss = URLEncoder.encode(jsonString);
```

and passing replacing this into the URL. But its not working. Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are posting on JsonObject to server. Use below code it works fine for me

```
    /**
 * Uplaod with Json Object
 * 
 * @param _requestedURL
 * @param obj
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String UploadUrl(String _requestedURL, JSONObject obj)
        throws IOException {
    HttpPost _request = new HttpPost(_requestedURL);
    HttpResponse _response = null;
    DefaultHttpClient _httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String _ContetnString = null;
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
        _request.setEntity(se);
        _request.setHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
        _request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                CommonValues.TIME_OUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,
                CommonValues.TIME_OUT);
        _request.setParams(httpParameters);
        _response = _httpClient.execute(_request);
        if (_response != null
                && _response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            //Read Responce
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return _ContetnString;
}
```

Comment: i doubt that making a post request qualifies as "passing an object as a url parameter". But i may have misunderstood the question

Comment: by doesn't qualifies, I mean that usually, url parameters implies that the parameter is past in the url, not in the post body, not that it doesn't work.